# Editing every element in the array to return an array of edited(sliced) elements

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to make edits to every element in the array to return an array of edited(sliced) elements. However, I am getting the error below. Any help is appreciated.

Traceback

```
>>> p=Playlist.objects.get(id=3)
>>> l=p.song.values_list('link', flat=True)
>>> print(l)
<QuerySet ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DqmVMlJzqA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DqmVMlJzqA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DqmVMlJzqA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6PiQr-lQY4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqOEoUR5RHg']>
>>> print([l[i][17:] if l[i][0:17] == 'https://youtu.be/'  else l[i][32:] for i in l])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 278, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

Comment: I don't think the objects are lists or other kinds of sequences. I think you are facing with QuesySet objects so you can't access the elements like lists. Can you try and print l[i]? and see the result?

Comment: `>>> print(l[i])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> print(l[1][32:])
_DqmVMlJzqA`

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh, that is what I got.

Comment: sorry i actually meant l[1]

Comment: l[1] works but not when i apply the ternary operator with the if statement.

Comment: if that returns a QuerySet object so you cannot compare it with string